# How do I restore revoked permissions on a google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I mistakenly revoked permissions on a google-apps-script that ran on a time trigger on a google spreadsheet from here: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions .  I now receive an email that the script fails to run. Going to the spreadsheet and editing the script fails to bring up the script, presumably because of the lack of permissions, but no error is shown, just a blank script editor.  I am able to see the trigger to the script (here: https://script.google.com/macros/triggers?id=some_id ), but I am not able to get to the script.

How can I restore or reinstate the permissions to this script?
Or how can I get the code to this script? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply revoked permissions it will not remove the actual script/coding. So it may not be attached to the spreadsheet you are opening. Perhaps you are opening the wrong spreadsheet, or it is a standalone-   If you type type:script into your google drive search it will show all scripts that are not bound to a spreadsheet.

As far as restoring you will just want to run it, once you find it.

Comment: A search in drive resulted in no scripts found. I am sure I am opening the right spreadsheet as it is linked-to in the email notification of the failure. I further see no way to get to the script from the trigger for the page.

Comment: have you tried to open the script editor on the spreadsheet you think is the correct one. Goto File/ See revision History- See if there are any revisions?

Answer (score 0):

I was successful. I'm not sure what did it but: previously I was not able to view the script, looking at the revision history doesn't allow me to get access to the menu and thus I was not able to get at older versions of the script.  But making a copy of the spreadsheet then allowed me to view the script again, both in the original and copy of the spreadsheet.  Running the script then requests for permission, restoring the permissions!

I really don't know if the lack of access to the script was a temporary condition or required that I make a copy of the spreadsheet, but this was the sequence of events that worked for me.

Thank you @OblongMedulla for making the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to your Google Profile - Manage Your Google Account - Security - Third Party Apps and revoke the permissions. If you want to use the app again, you'll have to run the script again from appscript and grant the permissions.